# How to convert ArrayList of Objects into separate JSON objects

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I am writing a JSP webapp and right now I'm kind of stuck. I have been using an ArrayList of Java Objects, each with a list of properties. They are Order objects with properties like firstName, lastName, etc. At this point in my development I need to store the individual orders as JSON arrays in javascript variables. I am able using a servlet to convert the arraylist to JSON but the JSON has repeat properties for each of the Order objects, like this:

[{firstName : Mike, lastName : Daniels,  ..... firstName : John, lastName : Doe ... etc ...}]

Clearly, the JSON is made up of all of my Order objects, strung together as one JSON array. What I am wondering is how I need to split up the string into separate variables depending on the number of Orders in the app at the time.

Here's how the object is set if it helps. Thanks!

```
   Object orders = request.getSession().getAttribute("orders");

    //this is a string of order properies/values
    String json = new Gson().toJson(orders);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("jsonOrders", json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating through the array list, creating a JSON object for each of the objects instead of converting the array list as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your orders entity is something like this:

```
public class Order {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getters & setters
}
```

and you get your orders data in request like:

```
  [{
    "firstName": "Mike",
    "lastName": "Daniels"
}, {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}]
```

You should be able to convert it to `List<Order>` using

```
List<Order> orders = gson.fromJson(response, Order.class);
```

You can then iterate over the list like:

```
for (Order order: orders) {
    // Whatever you want to do
}
```

Or, if you are using java 8:

```
orders.forEach (order -> System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using Gson library,

```
//Order.java
public class Order {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
}  

//Orders.java
public class Orders {
Order[] order;

public Order[] getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(Order[] order) {
    this.order = order;
}
}

import com.google.gson.Gson;
//Solution.java
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{\"order\":[{\"firstName\":\"Mike\",\"lastName\":\"Daniels\"},{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"}]}";
    Orders orders = new Gson().fromJson(json, Orders.class);
    Order[] orderArr = orders.getOrder();
    for(int i=0; i<orderArr.length;i++){
        System.out.println("First Name : "+ orderArr[i].getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name "+orderArr[i].getLastName());
    }
}

}

**Output**

First Name : Mike
Last Name Daniels
First Name : John
Last Name Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by ssc looks right. Best way to do is iterate through the list.